# Gps services to get current position

Tags: gps, tracking, gpsd

I want to know is there any services that device by using it could find it's current location?
for example tags that show current location , using any international or local
services.
thanks for any guides.
Regards
Ali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some thing more ,GPS is satellite network that send positions as a signal
to earth and receiver should get signal from at least four satellite to calculate
their current position.it is free and every receiver could use it.